# All possible types of permutation.

Tags: permutations

A permutation $ \sigma \in S_{10} $ satisfies the conditions $$ \forall_{1 \le i \le 29} \sigma^i \neq id, \sigma^{30} = id $$
Determine all possible types of the permutations.
Give me a hand.

Comment: HINT: $\text{lcm}(2,3,5)=30$

Answer (score 0):

The "type" of a permutation means its **cycle type**, i.e., how it factors into **disjoint cycles**. For example, here is a permutation of type $3,3,2,1,1$:
$$\sigma=(1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5\ 6)(7\ 8)(9)(10)$$
This is **not** the one of the permutations you're looking for because $\sigma^6=\mathrm{Id}$.